# Using multiple datareaders

Tags: c#

hi im making a code wherein all the database values from different tables appear in one form provided below:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM identification; SELECT * FROM height; SELECT * FROM weight; SELECT * FROM bloodpressure  WHERE eid like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'", conn);
conn.Open();

using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {       
        textBox3.Text = (dr["lastname"].ToString());
        textBox4.Text = (dr["firstname"].ToString());
        textBox2.Text = (dr["middlename"].ToString());
        textBox9.Text = (dr["sex"].ToString());
        textBox5.Text = (dr["birthdate"].ToString());
        textBox6.Text = (dr["age"].ToString());
        textBox10.Text = (dr["department"].ToString());
        textBox7.Text = (dr["address"].ToString());
        textBox11.Text = (dr["status"].ToString());
        textBox8.Text = (dr["contact"].ToString());
    }

    if (dr.NextResult())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox12.Text = (dr["height"].ToString());
        }
    }

    if (dr.NextResult())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox15.Text = (dr["weight"].ToString());
        }
    }

    if (dr.NextResult())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox16.Text = (dr["systole"].ToString());
            textBox17.Text = (dr["diastole"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

the code runs however only the values on the former `eid` appears whenever i tried to type another `eid`. what should i do so that all the values of a selected eid appears on the form?

Comment: Is the using statement closed after the last if? If not it may be something to do with a connection being left open and the UI not able to update until its closed. I.e when a new connection is made.

Comment: Important: you should parameterize that - it is currently very unsafe. Have you done anything like suspend UI updates / binding / drawing?

Comment: What triggers this code to run? Have you tried running it in a debugger to verify that it is getting the expected value in `textBox1.Text`?

Comment: @LexWebb nope. because i think it would still run fine.

Comment: Code shown is unlikely related to problem you see - which is most likely caused by listening to wrong event. You should be able to replace all this code with constant values (like `textBox1.Text + "weight"`) for debugging and still see the same effect. Please simplify code in the post and add missing pieces (this will also avoid embracing SQL injection code from being ridiculed).

Comment: @JackA. only the previous database values from the previous eid would appear on the textboxes whenever i tried to put another eid.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i dont get your idea, could you elaborate it?

Comment: @newbie replace this code in your program with `textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text + "lastname"` and try your steps - I bet you'll see exactly the same behavior as you see with this complicated code - which would confirm that error is somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the form wont open anymore. i dont think it needs textbox1.Text anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.

You have a problem somewhere else (Triggers , postback etc , maybe you have a n event order problem - try run it at the  `pre_render` event  ).

Looking at a real  `CITIES` table  (which contains 4 rows):

[image]

Running your *exact* code (with sql-server provider):

```
void Main()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=aaa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=-----;Password=------+");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                                @"SELECT * FROM cities; 
                                SELECT city as secondBulkCity FROM cities; 
                                SELECT  city as thirdBulkCity from cities; 
                                SELECT  city as fourthBulkCity from cities  WHERE city like '" + "new" + "%'", conn);
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
            "".Dump("first bulk");
                while (dr.Read())
                {       
                 dr["city"].Dump();
                }

            "".Dump("second bulk");
                 if (dr.NextResult())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        dr["secondBulkCity"].Dump();
                    }
                }

           "".Dump("third bulk");
                if (dr.NextResult())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                       dr["thirdBulkCity"].Dump();
                    }
                }
            "".Dump("fourth bulk");
                if (dr.NextResult())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                       dr["fourthBulkCity"].Dump();
                    }
                }
}


}
```

Yields this :

[image]

Your problem is not in this specific code you've shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Make cmd a global variable.

Generate a function for when the EID textbox is changed by the user. Usually done by double clicking the textbox in the design view. In this function you should update the cmd to incorporate the new eid. Then call your GUI update function.

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd;

[OnTextboxUpdate]
{
 cmd=new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM identification; SELECT * FROM height; SELECT * FROM weight; SELECT * FROM bloodpressure  WHERE eid like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'", conn);
 updateGUI();
}


[updateGUI]
{
   using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {       
                textBox3.Text = (dr["lastname"].ToString());
                textBox4.Text = (dr["firstname"].ToString());
                textBox2.Text = (dr["middlename"].ToString());
                textBox9.Text = (dr["sex"].ToString());
                textBox5.Text = (dr["birthdate"].ToString());
                textBox6.Text = (dr["age"].ToString());
                textBox10.Text = (dr["department"].ToString());
                textBox7.Text = (dr["address"].ToString());
                textBox11.Text = (dr["status"].ToString());
                textBox8.Text = (dr["contact"].ToString());
            }

            if (dr.NextResult())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    textBox12.Text = (dr["height"].ToString());
                }
            }

            if (dr.NextResult())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    textBox15.Text = (dr["weight"].ToString());
                }
            }

            if (dr.NextResult())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    textBox16.Text = (dr["systole"].ToString());
                    textBox17.Text = (dr["diastole"].ToString());
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: i already generated it on a button click so i think it would already cause an exception if ill generate another

Comment: Can you post the surrounding function? I am not sure when this function is being called?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       { (the code above)... conn.Close(); }